# Is there a way to get user which disconnected in discord py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to have an event triggered every time a specific user is disconnecting.

My intention was to use...

```
@client.event
async def on_disconnect():
    # check if specific user disconnected
```

...but according to discord py documentation there are now further arguments for this function. So I can't simply get which user triggered this client event.

Is there a way to get such information or do you know a different way to trigger an event if a specific user is disconnecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs [`on_disconnect`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_disconnect)

> Called when the client has disconnected from Discord.

You need to use [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update) and get the `after` member's `status`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Knowing this I will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(ctx, member : discord.Member):
      print(f'{member} has left the server')
```

And then instead of the print command, you could add a 'if-statement' or another way of checking for a specific user.
That's what I would do in this situation.

Hope it helped a bit.